# Enums in java compile error

Tags: java

I'm trying to learn java from bottom up, and I got this great book to read http://www.amazon.com/o/ASIN/0071591060/ca0cc-20 . Now I found example in the book about declaring Enums inside a class but outside any methods so I gave it a shot :

```
Enum CoffeeSize { BIG, HUGE, OVERWHELMING };
```

In the book its spelled `enum` and I get this compile message `Syntax error, insert ";" to complete BlockStatements`

Are the Enums that important at all?I mean should I skip it or its possible that I will be using those some day?

Comment: What version of Java do you have installed?  Type `java -version` at the command line to find out.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard java version "1.6.0_18", I'm even specifying that 1.6 be used while building the project with maven

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct way to declare an `enum` inside a class:

```
public class Main {
  enum Foo { One, Two, Three }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println(Foo.One);
  }
}
```

You use the `enum` keyword, not `Enum`, which is the superclass of all `enum` instances.

Comment: when I copy/paste your code I get this compile error from eclipse `enum cannot be resolved to a type`

Comment: @London OK, I know what that is. Your project is compiling as a target for Java 1.4. You need to change it to Java 5 or Java 6. Java enums didn't exist in 1.4. This is different to what JDK you're using. The project will have a setting about what version of the language to use.

Comment: you're right, howcome this project was compiling with 1.4 when I explicitly configured maven compile plugin to use 1.6 . thank you its the right answer

Answer (score 1):

As of Java 5, `enum` is a keyword, so capitalization is important.

As for whether you need to know them or not, it's really up to you.  They weren't even a part of the language for several versions, but they really are nice to have.  Quoting from the same book:

> ...you can guarantee that the compiler will stop you from assigning anything to a `CoffeSize` except `BIG`, `HUGE`, or `OVERWHELMING`.

Some people don't care for this, but I personally like to let the compiler do all the work I can get out of it.

(Also, the [Java Tutorials](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) are another great source for learning the basics.)

Comment: I think that there might be something wrong with my eclipse when I try to create enum class I get this error `Project 'progress' is not a J2SE 5.0 compliant project.` and when I try to declare enum by following examples from the book or tutorial you provided I get compile error

Comment: same error, anyways thank you for your time I'm off to bed now will try to google something tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ';'. You declare Enum like this.

```
enum CoffeeSize { BIG, HUGE, OVERWHELMING }
```

For more info please visit [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html)

Comment: Which version of Java you were using? I was able to compile and run the following,
public class Test {
 enum CoffeeSize { BIG, HUGE, OVERWHELMING }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println(CoffeeSize.BIG);
  }
}